# Is there a way to build set a variable as a JSON string in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-secrets

I would like to have an environment variable that its value is a JSON String, that is built from the `ExternalSecrets` variables.

```yaml
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: my-app-external-secret
spec:
  refreshInterval: "1h"
  secretStoreRef:
    name: hashicorp-vault
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
  target:
    creationPolicy: Owner
  data:

  - secretKey: SECRET_KEY_A
    remoteRef:
      key: microservice/my-app
      property: secret_key_a

  - secretKey: SECRET_KEY_B
    remoteRef:
      key: microservice/my-app
      property: secret_key_b
```

The output should look like:

```json
{
    "A": {
      "secretKey": "<SECRET_KEY_A>",
      "someStaticValue": "ABCDEF"
    },
    "B": {
      "secretKey": "<SECRET_KEY_B>",
      "someStaticValue": "FEDCBA"
    }
}
```

So then I could export it in the `Deployment` and be able to use it as a JSON string, something that might look like this:

```yaml
- name: JSON_SECRETS
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: my-app-external-secret
      key: jsonSecret
```

I've tried some stuff but didn't get it to work.
I can use `ConfigMap` if needed. I'm trying to achieve the following behavior in my app:
Whenever I need to implement a new secret, there is not need to modify the source code, only wait the refresh time or restart the pod. The application already knows how to handle the JSON, but I'm unable to create this JSON in the Kubernetes. It is a Java application, it doesn't need to be a JSON, it can also be a list.